# Redundancy of graph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have created a small graph in Neo4j and the respective nodes and relationships are created. If I run the same code again, the nodes and relationships are again created instead of displaying the message like the nodes and relationships already exist similar like Oracle.

```
MERGE (a:Person1 { name : 'ROGER', title : 'Developer', age :28})  
MERGE (b:Person2 { name : 'Britney', title : 'financier',age :32})  
MERGE (c:Person3 { name : 'Christian', title : 'tester',age :24}) 
Create (a)-[:HUSBAND{last_name:'WHITE'}]->(b) RETURN a,b,c;
```

So I want to clarify whether Neo4j has duplication or the nodes will be created many times

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the `MERGE` statements are not creating new persons, only your `CREATE` statement in the end, see http://console.neo4j.org/r/qrzr6u saying upon re-execution

```
created 1 relationship set 1 property
```

You probably want the MERGE on all statements:

```
MERGE (a:Person1 { name : 'ROGER', title : 'Developer', age :28 })
MERGE (b:Person2 { name : 'Britney', title : 'financier', age :32 })
MERGE (c:Person3 { name : 'Christian', title : 'tester', age :24 })
MERGE (a)-[:HUSBAND { last_name:'WHITE' }]->(b)
RETURN a,b,c;
```

See http://console.neo4j.org/r/vmfl2v for an example.

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` does not re-create data if it already exists.   `CREATE` always creates data, even if it already exists.

[The documentation on merge](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html) points out that it always matches on the full pattern.

In the case of the cypher snippet you gave us, if you ran it twice you should end up with only one copy of Roger, Britney, and Christian, but I would expect two separate relationships between Roger and Britney, because `CREATE` always creates.

Watch out for the gotcha on `MERGE` though, it always merges on the full pattern you specify.   So for example if you do this:

```
MERGE (a:Person {fname: "Henry"});
MERGE (a:Person {fname: "Henry", lname: "Banks"});
```

Then you get two Henrys, one with no lname property, and one with.  This is because the second `MERGE` looks for a Person node with fname:Henry, lname:Banks and fails to find it, so it creates one.  It does *not* add an extra property to an existing node.   This is a common trip-up using MERGE.

Another common trip-up using `MERGE` (again due to the "whole pattern match") is this:

```
MERGE (a:Person {name:"Henry"})-[:knows]->(b:Person {name: "Mary"});
MERGE (a:Person {name:"Henry"})-[:married]->(b:Person {name: "Mary"});
```

This ends up creating two Henry's and two Mary's.